# Content type template only for viewing, not editing

Tags: theming, 7, nodes

I've added a page template to override certain content types

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if( !empty($variables['node']) ) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

This successfully uses `page--node--vendor.tpl.php` instead of `page.tpl.php`

The problem is that it is also using this template when editing the node, which looks rather silly. How can I modify this to only use the template when viewing content and not when editing?

** Yes, I do want Drupal to use this theme when creating/editing content, and not a separate admin theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also key off of the path, eg, `node/1` is the path for viewing node 1, whereby `node/1/edit` is the path when you are editing node 1, therefore you could look `if arg(2) != 'edit'` ...

Answer (score 0):

This was the most convenient variable I found in the `$variables` array to check whether I was viewing or editing

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $is_editing = isset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#node_edit_form']) && $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#node_edit_form'];

  if( !empty($variables['node']) && !$is_editing ) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Comment: you could also key off of the path, eg, `node/1` is the path for viewing node 1, whereby `node/1/edit` is the path when you are editing node 1, therefore you could look if `arg(2)!='edit'`...